# Complex Group By clause to count by some column - Informix

Tags: database, group-by, informix

In the informix database, I have a table called `transactions` in which I have `trans_id`, `card_number`, `trans_date` and `trans_status` columns.

It can have duplicate `trans_id` values and some `trans_id` values even may have **null** values for some records.

Now, I need to group by these records based on `card_number`, `trans_date` and `trans_status`.

While doing so I should count record only once if `trans_id` is repeated and if `trans_id` is null then I should count it as **1** for every **null** `trans_id`.

So, for example, if I have 10 records for card number **12345678** in which 3 `trans_id` values are repeated (total 6) and one `trans_id` is unique and the remaining 3 `trans_id` are **nulls** then I should get the count as **7 for** that card number.

I tried the following query which is working in MySQL, but the same one is failing in Informix database where it is giving an error that the expression must be in group by clause.

```
SELECT 
    card_number, 
    (COUNT(*)+nulltransids-1) 
FROM (
        (SELECT 
            trans_id, 
            card_number, 
            (COUNT(*)-COUNT(trans_id)) AS nulltransids 
        FROM test.transactions 
        GROUP BY trans_id,card_number
        ) AS trans
    ) 
GROUP BY card_number;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this right you want the number of unique `trans_id` plus the number of rows with **NULL** `trans_id`. Try this:

```
SELECT card_number,
        COUNT(UNIQUE trans_id) + (COUNT(*) - COUNT(trans_id)) AS cnt
FROM transactions
GROUP BY card_number
```